# SQL Query - how do i group by the Unit Qty in this script

Tags: sql

writing a query to output a list of transfers and i need to group it by the Unit_Qty field. Can you help me write it? I've joined a couple of tables, see the below query:

```
SELECT RPT_TRANSFERS.TRANS_BATCH_NO, RPT_TRANSFERS.FROM_BRANCH_ID, 
RPT_TRANSFERS.TO_BRANCH_ID,
RPT_BRANCHES.BRANCH_DESC, RPT_TRANSFERS.DATE_OUT,
RPT_TRANSFERS.DATE_AUTH,RPT_HIERARCHY_BY_SIZE.COMP,
RPT_HIERARCHY_BY_SIZE.RET_GRP ,RPT_TRANSFERS.SKU_ID,
RPT_TRANSFERS.UNIT_QTY
  FROM [TISOREPORTS].[dbo].[RPT_TRANSFERS] 
  LEFT JOIN RPT_BRANCHES ON RPT_TRANSFERS.TO_BRANCH_ID=RPT_BRANCHES.BRANCH_ID
  LEFT JOIN RPT_HIERARCHY_BY_SIZE ON RPT_TRANSFERS.SKU_ID=RPT_HIERARCHY_BY_SIZE.SKU_ID
  where DATE_OUT between '2023-01-29' and '2023-02-04' 
  and FROM_BRANCH_ID = 1 
  and TO_BRANCH_ID in (
2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8,
9, 10, 11, 12,
13, 14, 15, 35,
37, 45, 46, 47)
```

I get these results:

| TRANS_BATCH_NO | FROM_BRANCH_ID | TO_BRANCH_ID | BRANCH_DESC | DATE_OUT | DATE_AUTH | COMP | RET_GRP | SKU_ID | UNIT_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000000343502 | 1 | 2 | Tiso EOE | 2023-01-31 07:05:17.510 | 2023-01-31 07:05:17.510 | ALPINE | EAP | 696838 | 1 |
| 000000343502 | 1 | 2 | Tiso EOE | 2023-01-31 07:05:17.510 | 2023-01-31 07:05:17.510 | BLUES | APPAREL | 920600 | 1 |
| 000000343923 | 1 | 2 | Tiso EOE | 2023-02-01 16:34:06.937 | 2023-02-01 16:34:06.937 | ALPINE | EAP | 632946 | 1 |
| 000000343630 | 1 | 4 | Tiso GOE | 2023-01-31 14:15:19.810 | 2023-01-31 14:15:19.810 | ALPINE | EAP | 700623 | 1 |
| 000000343472 | 1 | 13 | Tiso POE | 2023-01-30 15:33:00.663 | 2023-01-30 15:33:00.663 | ALPINE | EAP | 632453 | 1 |
| 000000343586 | 1 | 8 | Tiso Edinburgh | 2023-01-31 11:54:26.477 | 2023-01-31 11:54:26.477 | TISO | EAP | 723110 | 1 |
| 000000343630 | 1 | 4 | Tiso GOE | 2023-01-31 14:15:19.810 | 2023-01-31 14:15:19.810 | ALPINE | EAP | 840537 | 1 |
| 000000343923 | 1 | 2 | Tiso EOE | 2023-02-01 16:34:06.937 | 2023-02-01 16:34:06.937 | TISO | APPAREL | 932021 | 1 |
| 000000343637 | 1 | 45 | Alp Mar Closed | 2023-01-31 14:26:47.650 | 2023-01-31 14:26:47.650 | ALPINE | EAP | 964427 | 1 |
| 000000343823 | 1 | 2 | Tiso EOE | 2023-02-01 11:50:55.760 | 2023-02-01 11:50:55.760 | ALPINE | EAP | 920943 | 2 |

How do i group by, to get make it give me the results that i can add in to this spreadsheet:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhLvK.png)

when i group by just the UNIT_QTY field - i get the usual

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'TISOREPORTS.dbo.RPT_TRANSFERS.TRANS_BATCH_NO' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Please add some sample output what you are expecting and sample data of tables that you are joining for clear understanding.

Comment: This is a hard question to decipher. Some sample data and desired results (from that sample data) would help clarify what you are trying to do. As best I can guess right now, I think it's not so much "GROUP BY" that you should be investigating but "PIVOT".

Comment: @JNevill `PIVOT` is just a fancy `GROUP BY`, and less flexible. Question is, which columns to group and which to aggregate, it's not clear.

Comment: Its basically pivot i need to do. i need to get it to group by ret_grp, with a sum of the  Unit_qty
RET_GRP    UNIT_QTY (this would be a sum)
APPAREL    17 
BIKES     34
EAP     139 
FOOTWEAR  5

Comment: Hi - please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: I've used "Pivot" - managed to figure it out thanks